# Fuzzy Search in Solr with distance 3

Tags: solr

I am using Fuzzy Search in Solr like below -

Expected word - dolphin

```
Level 1 Search - dolpin~1 -> gives dolphin
Level 2 Search - dlphn~2 -> gives dolphin
Level 3 search - dlpn~3 -> does not give dolphin, gives some weird results like glen, den etc.
```

How to get dolphin in level 3 search ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with fuzzy search, as the [edit distance is limited to a maximum of two edits](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-FuzzySearches):

> An optional distance parameter specifies the maximum number of edits allowed, between 0 and 2, defaulting to 2.

In your case could probably get better results by using a (very) generalizing [phonetic algorithm](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/phonetic-matching.html).

If you look at what the fuzzy search represent (edit distance), you can see how `dlpn` matches `glen`:

```
dlpn -> (d|g)l(p|e)n -> glen
          ^     ^     
          2 edits
```

When you do fuzzy searching and have short terms, there will be more variance in the returned elements compared to what you're querying for.